# Could not build module

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

After Xcode update to v. 5.0.2 i can't build my app for iOS 6.0 target.
I can build only for iOS 7.0

I get many errors:

```
Could not build module CoreFoundation
Could not build module Darwin
Cyclic dependency in module Darwin: Darwin -> Foundation -> CoreFoundation -> Darwin
Could not build module Foundation
```

Interesting thing, is that before the update it was possible to compile the app for iOS 6.0, **BUT** I had the same errors when trying to compile app for iPhone 4/4S

PS. Build Settings - armv7, armv7s. **Without arm64.**